# How can I parse multiple URLs from a text file through BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to scrape the values of multiple URLs via BeautifulSoup.

I can successfully do it for one URL, but what I am hoping to do is pull in a list of around 300 URLs from a seperate text file.

How do I reference a text file of URLs instead of just the single URL in

`source = requests.get('https://notmyrealurl.com').text`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get('https://notmyrealurl.com').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, features="html.parser")

title = soup.find("meta", attrs={'itemprop': 'acquia_lift:content_keywords'})

print(title["content"] if title is not None else "No meta title given")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `open` and iterate through each line of URL.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("your_txt.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        url = line.rstrip()
        source = requests.get(url).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, features="html.parser")
        title = soup.find("meta", attrs={'itemprop': 'acquia_lift:content_keywords'})
        print(title["content"] if title is not None else "No meta title given")
```

I assume your txt file is

```
url1.com
url2.com
url3.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Your text file need to be a list: `['url1', 'url2', 'url3', '...']`.
Here is the config code to read text file:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# Read your text file
yourtextfile = open('yourtextfile.txt').read()
# import it into list
listurl = list(eval(yourtextfile))
for url in listurl:
    source = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, features="html.parser")
    title = soup.find("meta", attrs={'itemprop': 'acquia_lift:content_keywords'})
    print(title["content"] if title is not None else "No meta title given")
```